# A good framework for Image(DICOM) data manipulation, visualization and development

Tags: qt, opencv, vtk, dicom, itk

I need to start a project which deals with the DICOM data manipulation, visualization. As a part of some basic research, I have found there are a few toolkits such as ITK, VTK which performs data manipulation on the medical image data. My question is, using ITK+VTK+QT for DICOM image manipulation(segmentation & registration) a better choice or using ITK with OpenCV would be a better option? Or any alternate toolkits exists that would likely achieve my requirement?

Any suggestions, sources or links related to this topic would be much helpful.

Comment: Too much of an opinion question I guess. I would suggest you start with GDCM (grass roots dicom). Learn some stuff before making a decision. There are other libraries which you can evaluate when you have tried some basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many toolkits and frameworks that work with Dicom. It depends on what you want to do.

In many cases, the easiest thing to do is to build a plugin for an existing application/toolkit such as [Horos](https://www.horosproject.org), [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org), [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/), [MITK](http://mitk.org/wiki/MITK), [MeVisLab](http://www.mevislab.de), [ITK Snap](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php), etc. I'm sure there are dozens more.

If you want to build your own medical imaging application, most of the above are open-source; adapting one of these would save you a lot of grief (and probably years) compared to trying to write your own application from scratch.

If your main interest is in developing algorithms, then Python is a good prototyping language - consider packages such as numpy, scipy, pydicom, ITK, SimpleITK. Java has [dcm4chee](http://www.dcm4che.org). C++ has [QT](https://www.qt.io/developers/), ITK, VTK.

If you want to do something JavaScript-based that will work though web browsers on tablets etc, look at in-progress projects such as [OHIF Viewer](http://ohif.org) or [Cornerstone](https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone).

One other thing: a) dealing with Dicom data, b) manipulation and c) visualisation, are three different things. It's easy to convert your Dicom data to, say, `nifti` format, which opens up a lot of academic analysis tools. Similarly, there are many 2D and 3D visualisation libraries that are not specific to Dicom - it's just about converting data into the right form.